# How to use a Lambda function with Reduce to repeat row N numbre f time in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets

Hello I've tried using text manipulation to achieve the results, and while it works - I don't think it's an efficient way to do it and there is limitations with how many times it can be done.

I was trying to figure out how to get it done with reduce but it having hard time to figure it out.

This is the current table

| Unique ID | Some other Info | How many times to repeat |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | Some Info | 2 |
| 456 | Some Info | 3 |

The result would be

| Unique ID |
| --- |
| 123 |
| 123 |
| 456 |
| 456 |
| 456 |

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way to do this:

```
=ArrayFormula(REDUCE("Unique ID",SEQUENCE(COUNTA(A2:A)),LAMBDA(a,c,{a;IF(SEQUENCE(INDEX(C2:C,c)),INDEX(A2:A,c))})))
```

### Explanation

The LAMBDA inside REDUCE works by taking 3 parameters: an accumulator (a), a current value (c) and the operation to perform using them.

The accumulator (a) is initialized to the first argument of REDUCE, which is `"Unique ID"` and every time the inner LAMBDA is executed, the accumulator updates with the result of that execution.

The current value (c) is a variable parameter and it takes on all the values provided in the second argument of REDUCE `SEQUENCE(COUNTA(A2:A)) (1)`.

Let's assume (1) returns:

```
1
2
```

The main work happens here:

```
{a;IF(SEQUENCE(INDEX(C2:C,c)),INDEX(A2:A,c))} (2)
```

Before this piece of code is executed, `a` has a value of "Unique ID" and `c` has a value of 1.

When it executes for the first time, `a` and `c` are replaced with their initial value, so we get:

```
{"Unique ID";IF(SEQUENCE(INDEX(C2:C,1)),INDEX(A2:A,1))}
```

Now `c` becomes 2 and `a` becomes

```
{"Unique ID";IF(SEQUENCE(INDEX(C2:C,1)),INDEX(A2:A,1))}
```

So when (2) is executed for the second time, this is what we get:

```
{{"Unique ID";IF(SEQUENCE(INDEX(C2:C,1)),INDEX(A2:A,1))};
IF(SEQUENCE(INDEX(C2:C,2)),INDEX(A2:A,2))}
```

We have now gone through all the values of `c` so the formula stops executing and that's effectively what it returns.

The amount of iterations `REDUCE` does depends on the size of its second parameter.

Let's see another example. Assume (1) returns:

```
1
2
3
```

First time c=1, a="Unique ID":

```
{"Unique ID";IF(SEQUENCE(INDEX(C2:C,1)),INDEX(A2:A,1))}
```

Second time c=2, a=PREVIOUSLY_RETURNED_ARRAY:

```
{{"Unique ID";IF(SEQUENCE(INDEX(C2:C,1)),INDEX(A2:A,1))};
IF(SEQUENCE(INDEX(C2:C,2)),INDEX(A2:A,2))}
```

Third and last time c=3, a=PREVIOUSLY_RETURNED_ARRAY:

```
{{{"Unique ID";IF(SEQUENCE(INDEX(C2:C,1)),INDEX(A2:A,1))};
IF(SEQUENCE(INDEX(C2:C,2)),INDEX(A2:A,2))};
IF(SEQUENCE(INDEX(C2:C,3)),INDEX(A2:A,3))}
```

And that's the array `REDUCE` returns.

Do you see a pattern?

Comment: Thank you - this is exactly what I was looking for. Would it be possible to explain the logic behind it?

Comment: happy to help! added explanation. :)

Comment: awesome - very clear - thank you

Answer (score 0):

A different approach could be-

```
=QUERY(FLATTEN(INDEX(SPLIT(REPT(A2:A3&"|",C2:C3),"|"))),"where Col1 is not null")
```

[image]